# Plotly - update the chart without open it in new tab over and over again

Tags: python, charts, plotly

How can I update the chart in real-time instead of re-opening it again and again ? I have used plotly only and it looks like fig.show() keep re-opening a new tab instead of just updating the chart..

```
import ibapi
import pandas
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
      def __init__(self):
           EClient.__init__(self, self)
           self.data = [] #Initialize variable to store candle
      def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
           print(f'Time: {bar.date} High: {bar.high} Low: {bar.low} Open: {bar.open} Close : 
                                                                             {bar.close}')
           self.data.append([bar.date, bar.high, bar.low, bar.open, bar.close])

def run_loop():
    app.run()
 
app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, 123)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) 

#contract object
eurusd_contract = Contract()
eurusd_contract.symbol = 'EUR'
eurusd_contract.secType = 'CASH'
eurusd_contract.exchange = 'IDEALPRO'
eurusd_contract.currency = 'USD'



i=1
while i==1:
    app.reqHistoricalData(1, eurusd_contract, '', '2 D', '1 hour', 'BID', 1, 2, False, [])
    time.sleep(5)  #sleep to allow enough time for data to be returned

    df = pandas.DataFrame(app.data, index=None, columns=['DateTime','High', 'Low', 'Open', 
                                                     'Close'])
    df['DateTime'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],unit='s') 
    df.to_csv('EURUSD_Hourly.csv')
    #print(df)
    time.sleep(5)



    fig = go.Figure(data=[ 
          go.Candlestick(
          x=df['DateTime'],
          open=df['Open'],
          high=df['High'],
          low=df['Low'],
          close=df['Close'])])

    fig = fig.update_layout(title= 'INTERACTIVE CHART',
                            yaxis_title = eurusd_contract.symbol)

    fig.show()
    time.sleep(10)
```

The chart is being opened every update on different tab, how can i update it without open a new tab?

Comment: Create a Dash application?

Comment: This isn't possible in plotly – you would need to create a Dash application where the data in the plot can be updated with new data that isn't preloaded

Comment: You can use `plotly.io` and add `post_script` if you are somewhat knowledgeable in Javascript. Alternatively, suppose you have specific data options you want to see in the graph. In that case, you could use `updatemenus` and add Plotly buttons to see different perspectives or entirely different data sets.